# AWS OpsWorks use file as an Environment Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

Cheers!
Is there any possibility to use File (.pem certificate in my occasion) as an AWS OpsWorks Environment Variable?
As far as I could see, AWS OpsWorks allows to set only direct string values through it's console on app's level.

Or maybe there are some best practices of storing .pem certificates on AWS that depends on environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's file, it would be better to store in S3. Therefore,  you can pass the S3 URL as the environment variable. And a custom recipe could download the file from S3.